# how to unclick a button after it has been clicked in pyqt5(resetting it)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

so i am programming in pyqt5, and i have a function that catches all of the buttons that have been clicked, so the problem is that the function contains if statements like, if

```
self.bo.clicked:
blah blah blah
```

and so forth with about a dozen buttons or so,
so the problem is once a button is clicked its .clicked value automatically becomes permanently True, is and if the different buttons have been clicked previously all of the if statements get triggered, I am wondering is there any way to dis-arm the .clicked property?

what i have tried is:

```
if self.b0.clicked:
    self.bo.setEnabled(False)
    self.bo.setEnabled(True)
#attempting to reset the button.
```

however that doesn't work, and once a button has been "clicked" and when i click another button they all automatically fire up. 
I am a bit new to this, so please help me. Or maybe explain another way to do this?
please and thank you!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'yevsCalcUi.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.work = []
        self.operators = []
        self.wrking = 0
        self.blin = 0
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(350, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_4)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_4)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.numbers = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.numbers.setObjectName("numbers")
        self.numbers.setText("blin")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.numbers, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.b3.setObjectName("b3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.b3, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.bac = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.bac.setObjectName("bac")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bac, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.bmul = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.bmul.setObjectName("bmul")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bmul, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.splitter_3 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.frame_2)
        self.splitter_3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_3.setObjectName("splitter_3")
        self.b7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_3)
        self.b7.setObjectName("b7")
        self.b8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_3)
        self.b8.setObjectName("b8")
        self.b9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_3)
        self.b9.setObjectName("b9")
        self.bmin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_3)
        self.bmin.setObjectName("bmin")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.splitter_3, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        self.bd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.bd.setObjectName("bd")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bd, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.bdiv = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.bdiv.setObjectName("bdiv")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bdiv, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.b1.setObjectName("b1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.b1, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.frame_2)
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
        self.b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_2)
        self.b4.setObjectName("b4")
        self.b5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_2)
        self.b5.setObjectName("b5")
        self.b6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_2)
        self.b6.setObjectName("b6")
        self.bplu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter_2)
        self.bplu.setObjectName("bplu")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.splitter_2, 2, 0, 1, 4)
        self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.b2.setObjectName("b2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.b2, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.bpm = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.bpm.setObjectName("bpm")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bpm, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.beq = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.beq.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 25))
        self.beq.setObjectName("beq")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.beq, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(572, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 292, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 997, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.b0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.b0.setObjectName("b0")
        numbas = []
        self.b0.setProperty('0', numbas)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.b0, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.i = 0

        self.b0.clicked.connect(self.changeLabel)

        self.bplu.clicked.connect(self.changeLabel)


    def changeLabel(self):
        self.blin = self.blin + 1
        print("blin")
        self.numbers.setText("0")
        if self.b0.clicked:
            print("okay now that is Legit!")
            self.b0.setEnabled(False)
            self.b0.setEnabled(True)
            self.numbers.setText("0")
        if self.bplu.clicked:
            self.blin = 0
            print(self.blin)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.numbers.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:24pt;\">blinulator</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.b3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.bac.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AC"))
        self.bmul.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.b7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.b8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.b9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.bmin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.bd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "."))
        self.bdiv.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.b0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.b1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.b4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.b5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.b6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.bplu.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.b2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.bpm.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+/-"))
        self.beq.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))




app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: No, I have not asked you for a link (a link can be broken making your question useless for future readers), I have asked you for an MRE.

Comment: okay just a second

Comment: i am working on making it minimal, just a few edits.

Comment: cant really hack away at it, because i created it using qt designer whenever i try to cut something, it spits out errors.

Comment: your objective is to identify which button was pressed and clearly foo.clicked is not the solution since it will always be truly, in one of the duplicate questions I point out with several examples how to do that. On the other hand, do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer, but you should use the PyQt guidelines as the inheritance that I explain in the answer of the other duplicate question.